# Api response is not updating which causing first call fail

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, retrofit, viewmodel, kotlin-coroutines

```
 var authViewModel: UserAuthViewModel = hiltViewModel()
    val userData by authViewModel.authUserData.collectAsState()

fun checkUserforEmnail(
    sharedViewModel: SharedViewModel,
    userData: AuthResponseModel?,
    authViewModel : UserAuthViewModel,
    navController: NavController,
    textUser: String
) {
    Log.d("TAG", "checkUserforEmnail: ${userData}")
    if (userData == null){
        authViewModel.getAuthUserDataEmail(textUser = textUser)
        Log.d("TAG", "checkUserforEmnail: ${userData}")
    }
    if(userData?.result?.user_exist == "USER_NOT_EXISTS"){
        navController.navigate(NavScreens.REGISTRATION.route)
    }
    else if(userData?.result?.user_exist == "ACCOUNT_EXISTS") {
        sharedViewModel.addUsername(userName = textUser)
        navController.navigate(NavScreens.LOGIN.route)
    }
    else if(userData?.result?.user_exist == "ACCOUNT_NOT_VERIFIED"){

    }

}
```

```
ViewModel

@HiltViewModel
class UserAuthViewModel @Inject constructor(private val repository: Repository) : ViewModel()  {

    val authUserData: StateFlow<AuthResponseModel?> get() = repository.authUserData

    fun getAuthUserData(textUser: String, countryCode:String){
        viewModelScope.launch {
            val result = repository.getAuthUserData(AuthUser(username = textUser, country_dial_code = countryCode))
        }
    }

    fun getAuthUserDataEmail(textUser: String) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            val result = repository.getAuthUserData(AuthUser(username = textUser))
        }
    }
}
```

so the problem is that i call this fun on a click okk so on the first click i logged the userdata as null but then when i click it again it gets the data as intended, so what i think is happening is that because the response is taking a bit time which is normal time my code is not waiting for a response and hence having the default response as null and using that but in second time it uses the new data in the userData and i see the response. so my question is how do i solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your data flow correctly, you send request to `getAuthUserDataEmail`, ignore the returned value but collect the `AuthResponseModel` from `repository.authUserData` instead. This is a bug prone approach because you don't know which `authUserData` value corresponds to which `getAuthUserData` call.

Instead of using `authUserData` flow and doing buisiness logic in a `Composable` use the value returned by `repository.getAuthUserData` and update your UI state in the same coroutine in the `UserAuthViewModel`. Composable should navigate based on that UI state.

Example `ViewModel`:

```
sealed class AuthState {
    object SignedOut : AuthState()
    object Exist : AuthState()
    object NotExist : AuthState()
    object NotVerified : AuthState()
}

@HiltViewModel
class UserAuthViewModel @Inject constructor(private val repository: Repository) : ViewModel()  {
    private val _authState = MutableStateFlow<AuthState>(AuthState.SignedOut)
    val authState: StateFlow<AuthState>
        get() = _authState

    fun getAuthUserDataEmail(textUser: String) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            val userData = repository.getAuthUserData(AuthUser(username = textUser))
            // update UI state here
            if (userData?.result?.user_exist == "USER_NOT_EXISTS") {
                _authState.value = AuthState.NotExist
            }
            // rest of the logic
        }
    }
}
```

Composable:

```
val authState by authViewModel.authState.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()

LaunchedEffect(authState) {
    when (authState) {
        AuthState.Exist -> { navController.navigate(NavScreens.LOGIN.route) }
        AuthState.NotExist -> TODO()
        AuthState.NotVerified -> TODO()
        AuthState.SignedOut -> TODO()
    }
}
```

Comment: okkk so now it have a side effect with using this method see launched effect is launched whenever the value changes
    LaunchedEffect(authState) {
        when (authState) {
            AuthState.Exist -> { navController.navigate(NavScreens.LOGIN.route) }
            AuthState.NotExist -> { navController.navigate(NavScreens.REGISTRATION.route) }
            AuthState.NotVerified -> TODO()
//            AuthState.SignedOut -> TODO()
            else -> {}
        }
    }

so when i press back this block is called again and i go back to the register page im tring to solve this issue

Comment: so i somehow made it work but i have a question 
private val _authState = MutableStateFlow<AuthState>(AuthState.SignedOut)
here you have SignedOut as default how will i make this dynamic i need to keep this as same the result i get in response or it wont work

Comment: You can't change the initial value of a `StateFlow` once it declared, but you can always update its value `_authState.value =`. Or you could add a new `AuthState` value to indicate that last state was consumed. @PriyanshuRaj

Comment: doesnt solve my problem \